# How to make use of sparse matrix to optimise evaluation on many shifted points

Tags: r, performance, optimization, microbenchmark

I'm currently trying to solve the following problem efficiently:

I have two vectors `v1`, `v2` as well as a vectorised function `f`. For each `x` in `v1` I'd like to compute the mean of `f(x - v2)`. Special about this problem is that `f` will return zero on many inputs.

**Example:**

```
set.seed(0)

v1 <- rnorm(1000)
v2 <- rnorm(1000)

f <- function(x) {
  ret <- double(length(x)) + 1
  ret[abs(x) > 0.01] <- 0
  ret
}

solution_01 <- function(v1, v2, f) {
  ret <- numeric(length(v1))
  for (x in v2) {
    ret <- ret + f(v1 - x)
  }
  ret/length(v2)
}

solution_02 <- function(v1, v2, f) {
  apply(matrix(f(outer(v1, v2, `-`)), nrow=length(v1)), 1, sum)/length(v2)
}

solution_03 <- function(v1, v2, f) {
  rowSums(matrix(f(outer(v1, v2, `-`)), nrow=length(v1)))/length(v2)
}

solution_04 <- function(v1, v2, f) {
  rowMeans(matrix(f(outer(v1, v2, `-`)), nrow=length(v1)))
}

s1 <- solution_01(v1, v2, f)
s2 <- solution_02(v1, v2, f)
s3 <- solution_03(v1, v2, f)
s4 <- solution_04(v1, v2, f)

all.equal(s1, s2)
all.equal(s2, s3)
all.equal(s3, s4)

bench::mark(solution_01(v1, v2, f), solution_02(v1, v2, f), solution_03(v1, v2, f), solution_04(v1, v2, f))

# Sparsity
eval_points <- outer(v1, v2, `-`)
sum(f(eval_points) == 0)/length(eval_points)
```

As you can see I already implemented four possible solutions. For now the *naive* solution (using a for loop) is the fastest. I think this is because the other implementations rely on `outer`, which takes some time to allocate the required memory.

How can I optimise this code? Is there a way to make use of the sparsity of `f(outer(v1, v_2))`?

Comment: I think you're mainly interested in speed. 
I think the use of a sparse matrix to store the result would be mostly useful in terms of memory, not speed. If you need more speed, I would go for Rcpp in this situation.

Comment: @F.Privé What could Rcpp do in this situation? Would I write this exact loop just in c++? I'm familiar with basic C++ but can't do much optimisation. How much of an impact would it have?

Comment: @F.Privé I tried using Rcpp and asked the follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424356/how-to-optimise-rcpp-function-calling-another-r-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've presented (which I appreciate may be a simplification of what you are actually trying to do) would be efficiently solved by using sorted vectors, especially if the vectors got much longer than 1000 elements.

Since you are counting the values in `v2` within a small distance of the values in `v1` you could have an algorithm which advanced through the first vector until it got out of range of the element under consideration in the second, and then switch to advancing through the other vector. That way you only have to pass through each of the vectors once rather than `length(v1)` times.

As pointed out R isn't efficient at this sort of thing and you should code the whole thing in Rcpp if you want it to be really fast.

...

Thought I'd have a go at writing an algorithm for fun, turns out it is nearly 10 times faster on your example data even when written in R!

```
solution_05 <- function(v1, v2, f) {
  vs1 <- sort(v1)
  vs2 <- sort(v2)
  n1 <- integer(length(v1))
  i1 <- 1
  i2 <- 1
  l <- length(v1)
  for (x2 in vs2) {
    # advance i1 until v1 is in range below
    while (x2-vs1[i1] > 0.01 & i1 <= l) i1 <- i1+1
    if (i2 > i1) n1[i1:(i2-1)] <- n1[i1:(i2-1)]+1 else i2 <- i1
    # advance i2 until out of range adding 1 to n1[i2] each time
    while (vs1[i2]-x2 <= 0.01 & i2 <= l) {
      n1[i2] <- n1[i2]+1
      i2 <- i2+1
    }
  }
  s5 <- n1[rank(v1)]/length(v2)
  return(s5)
}
```